# Error Not Yet Implemented with Webpack when run node dist/server.js

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-universal

I were following the [guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering) to implement Angular Universal for my application. Everything worked out well until the last command `node dist/server.js` throw an error `Error: NotYetImplemented`

The full traceback is here:
`bash
Error: NotYetImplemented
    at HTMLCanvasElement.exports.nyi (C:\Users\dist\server.js:50200:9)
    at C:\Users\dist\server.js:238837:55
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dist\server.js:228511:20)
    at svgNS (C:\Users\dist\server.js:228512:12)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Users\dist\server.js:228520:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dist\server.js:228463:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dist\server.js:228427:89)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\dist\server.js:20:30)`

The current version of the packages in my application can be viewed here in package.json:
`json
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --production && ng build --production --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "pre-commit": [
    "ng lint -fix"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.3.1",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.4",
    "@ngui/auto-complete": "0.14.4",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "0.3.1",
    "@types/flickity": "2.0.0",
    "angular-spinners": "5.0.2",
    "angular2-drag-scroll": "1.5.2",
    "bodymovin": "4.13.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "express": "4.16.2",
    "flickity": "2.0.10",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng-lottie": "0.3.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "3.0.3",
    "ng-selectize": "1.1.3",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-device-detector": "1.0.1",
    "ng2-input-autocomplete": "0.0.11",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.2",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-loading": "1.0.14",
    "node-sass": "4.7.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "selectize": "0.12.4",
    "slick-carousel": "1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "8.9.3",
    "bootstrap-loader": "2.2.0",
    "chalk": "2.3.1",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.4.1",
    "cssnano": "4.0.0-rc.2",
    "domino": "2.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "4.0.0-beta.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "graceful-fs": "4.1.11",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "jsdom": "11.6.2",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "lottie-web": "5.1.7",
    "memory-fs": "0.4.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.2",
    "protractor": "5.3.0",
    "sass-lint": "1.12.1",
    "tapable": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "ts-loader": "3.5.0",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "uglify-js": "3.3.10",
    "webpack": "3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "3.0.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.6.0"
  }
}`

webpack.server.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: './src/server.ts'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  },
  target: 'node',
  // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: 'ts-loader'
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for 'WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression'
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), {}
    )
  ]
};
```

Anyone saw the same problem can give me some insights? Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like it may be coming from ng2-charts : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234347/notyetimplemented-error-ng2-charts (don't know if there is a known solution)

Comment: Or domino, actually

Comment: what do you think? Should I remove these packages?

Comment: If you don't need them for your app, then yes

Comment: actually, I can't remove `ng2-charts` but I will try with `domino`, is there any way to know which is the problem than removing one by one package?

Comment: You need to have a look at the failing code. This not implemented exception is definitely thrown in domino

Comment: I can't remove domino due to I need it in my `server.ts` file. How can you know this exception come from domino?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165041/discussion-between-david-and-tho-vo).

Comment: I've got this exact same error and it does come from domino - domino (DOM in Node) has not implemented canvas - how did you work around this? thx

Comment: @danday74 I don't remember exactly what I had done, it was 3 years ago, my recommendation for you is wrap your code with using canvas in comment, implement angular universal first, you can fix the problem with canvas later when you already finished updating universal